# handling for loop exceptions

Tags: python, for-loop, exception

```
a = 6
item_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
for items in item_list:
    if items == a:
        print("match found")
    else:
        print ("no match")
```

In this code I want "no match" to be printed only once after completing all the iterations; not on every iteration. How can I modify the code?

Comment: `is_match_found = a in item_list` You don't need an explicit for loop for that.

Answer (score 5):

Use instead:

```
a = 6
item_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
if a in item_list:
    print("match found")
else:
    print ("no match")
```

No need to iterate list by yourself, use built-in method.

Comment: Consider this situation: Instead of a list of integers, I have a list of objects with item_id as one of it's field variables . Now I need to compare the variable 'a' with the item_id of each objects and if there is no match , print "no match" only once .

Comment: It requires to provide an another example, so consider just asking another question to not complicate and redefine already answered topics.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, the most efficient solution in this situation is to use an `in` test, and no explicit loop is needed.

However, in a more general situation where one is looping until a match is found (if more complex logic means that there is no simple equivalent of `in` available), it is worth remembering that a `for` loop can have an `else` block which is run after the loop completes if it is has not been exited using `break`.  Taking this code as an example (even though not necessary in this situation), you could do:

```
a = 6
item_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
for item in item_list:
    if item == a:
        print("match found")
        break
else:
    print ("no match")
```

Note that this is not exactly equivalent to the code in the question if *more than one* match is found, as here "match found" is only printed once and then the loop is exited via `break`.  If you were looking for potentially more than one match, for example saving these to a list, then you would not use `break` and `else`, but would instead test afterwards whether your output list was empty before printing "no match".

Comment: I know this is an old post but this should be the accepted answer. It helped me in my case so thank you.

Comment: @bmasri Glad that it was of use to you. For your information, the accepted answer (if any) is chosen by person who asked the question, and in this case they have not been active recently on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through, you can use `index` on `list` or using `in` operator

```
In [39]: a = 6
    ...: item_list = [1,2,3,4,5]

In [40]: try:
    ...:     index = item_list.index(a)
    ...:     print("match found")
    ...: except:
    ...:     print("no match")
    ...:
no match

In [41]: if a in item_list:
    ...:     print("match found")
    ...: else:
    ...:     print("no match")
    ...:
no match
```

Answer (score 0):

`a in b` is generally a better solution, but if you want to loop through the entire list you could create a variable to store
matches in and check if the variable is populated when the for-loop expires.

```
a = 6
memory = []
item_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
for items in item_list:
    if items == a:
         memory.append(a)
         print("match found")
if len(memory) == 0:
    print("No matches")
```

`a` is never gonna show up in the loop since you're only looping over elements in item_list, fyi

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 6
item_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
found_in_list_boolean = False

for items in item_list:
    if items == a:
        print("match found")
        '''Set the boolean to True as you reached the match found statement '''
        found_in_list_boolean = True

'''2 ways from here'''

'''First Way : If found_in_list_boolean is true print something and for false print not found'''
if (found_in_list_boolean):
    print("Found")
else:
    print("not found")


'''Second Way :If found_in_list_boolean is false and print'''
if (found_in_list_boolean==False):
    print("not Found")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `while` loop:

```
a = 6
item_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
i = 0
found = False
while True:
    i += 1
    if item_list[i] == 6:
        print("Found")
        found = True
    if i > len(item_list):
        break
if not found:
    print("Not found")
```

Note that 6 is not in the list, so it will `print` `"Not found"`